# __dict__ for an object not showing @property attribute

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

When using decorators, I am setting an attribute through "setter" decorator, however it doesn't show up in object's **dict**.
Below is my code

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.f_name = first
        self.l_name = last
        self.email = self.f_name + '.' + self.l_name + '@hotmail.com'
    
    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.f_name,self.l_name) )


    @fullname.setter
    def fullname(self, name):
        first, last = name.split(' ')
        self.f_name = first
        self.l_name = last
        self.email = self.f_name + '.' + self.l_name + '@hotmail.com'
        
emp_1 = Employee('Sandeep', 'Behera')
print(emp_1.__dict__)


emp_1.fullname = "Alex Smith"
print(emp_1.__dict__)

emp_1.age = 20
print(emp_1.__dict__)
```

Running above, the result is :

```
{'f_name': 'Sandeep', 'l_name': 'Behera', 'email': 'Sandeep.Behera@hotmail.com'}
{'f_name': 'Alex', 'l_name': 'Smith', 'email': 'Alex.Smith@hotmail.com'}
{'f_name': 'Alex', 'l_name': 'Smith', 'email': 'Alex.Smith@hotmail.com', 'age': 20}
```

Why the "fullname" isn't showing up in the Dict even when I am assigning

```
emp_1.fullname = "Alex Smith"
```

but it shows "age" attribute. Does it have to do something with decorators?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Why the "fullname" isn't showing up in the Dict even when I am assigning?* The same reason why `__init__` doesn't show up in the `__dict__`. It's method of your class. It's just decorated with `@property` which makes it look like an attribute but it is not an attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your decorated setter does not create an attribute `fullname`.
Adding a new line to your setter as follows will give you an attribute `full_name`:

```
@fullname.setter
def fullname(self, name):
    first, last = name.split(' ')
    self.f_name = first
    self.l_name = last
    self.email = self.f_name + '.' + self.l_name + '@hotmail.com'
    self.full_name = name      # creating an attribute full_name
```

The result is as follows:

```
{'f_name': 'Sandeep', 'l_name': 'Behera', 'email': 'Sandeep.Behera@hotmail.com'}
{'f_name': 'Alex', 'l_name': 'Smith', 'email': 'Alex.Smith@hotmail.com', 'full_name': 'Alex Smith'}
{'f_name': 'Alex', 'l_name': 'Smith', 'email': 'Alex.Smith@hotmail.com', 'full_name': 'Alex Smith', 'age': 20}
```